# C# : file copy notifying

Tags: c#, io, filesystemwatcher

hi i am creating a c# application that monitor the files that has been copied , the aim of program is to alert user that there is a file has been copied , i know the file system watcher class , but it has only 4 events , change or create or delete or rename , is there a way to know if file has been copied in or out of system ?

Comment: Some of those 4 events will fire on such copies.

Comment: it could be the change event ?

Comment: Are you means want to monitor the files that copy from other system INTO your system, and the file from your system is copy OUT to another system? The FileSystemWatcher event will not tell you a file is copied from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a file is copied into the system you will also get a `change` or `create` event. But if it is simply accessed (which is what happens when it is copied) `FileSystemWatcher` is of no use.

You can use [Auditing file and folder access](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_evmonevents_17.mspx?mfr=true) feature of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The task makes no sense. First of all, there's no "copy" operation on the OS level. Copy is a sequence of open/read/close (source) + create/write/close (dest) operations. Now, even if such operation existed (eg. Explorer has such concept), what about archiving the file and then copying out the archive?